# Login to Memrise with Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to login to http://memrise.com/login with python. I tried a lot with the requests package, but it didn't work. Additionally I am a noob at HTTP requests.

Comment: are you doing this in order to scrape the webpage for data? please clarify this in your answer

Comment: Yes, I have to login to get special data.

Comment: If you are a "noob" at something you are trying you need to learn then -
 pretty obvious. Please read up on the basics before posting to SO.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of examples in unofficial memrise API doctumentation: https://github.com/carpiediem/memrise-enhancement-suite/wiki/Unofficial-Documentation-for-the-Memrise-API

I tried an url in python console. I suppose, it works:

```
[rudskoy-osx.local rudskoy@ ~/Downloads] $ python
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 12:39:47)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://www.memrise.com/api/pool/get/?pool_id=13535')
>>> r.json()
{u'pool': {u'can_curate': False, u'name': u'Mandarin', u'can_moderate': False, u'attributes': {u'1': {u'kind': u'text', u'show_at_tests': True, u'label': u'Part of Speech'}, u'4': {u'kind': u'text', u'show_at_tests': False, u'label': u'Measure Word'}}, u'id': 13535, u'columns': {u'1': {u'kind': u'text', u'typing_disabled': True, u'typing_strict': False, u'label': u'Word', u'always_show': True, u'classes': [u'bigger'], u'show_after_tests': False, u'keyboard': u'', u'tapping_disabled': False}, u'3': {u'kind': u'text', u'typing_disabled': False, u'typing_strict': False, u'label': u'Pronunciation', u'always_show': True, u'classes': [], u'show_after_tests': False, u'keyboard': u'', u'tapping_disabled': True}, u'2': {u'kind': u'text', u'typing_disabled': False, u'typing_strict': False, u'label': u'Definition', u'always_show': True, u'classes': [], u'show_after_tests': False, u'keyboard': u'', u'tapping_disabled': True}, u'4': {u'kind': u'audio', u'typing_disabled': False, u'typing_strict': False, u'label': u'Audio', u'always_show': False, u'classes': [], u'show_after_tests': False, u'keyboard': u'', u'tapping_disabled': False}}}}
>>>
```

If you want to authenticate and 'scrap' data without API you may use another libraries. I think this article may help you: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/authentication.shtml